# Notify android service when notification is clicked

Tags: android, service, notifications, android-notifications

I have a music service playing in background. Whenever some action happens on notification i want to listen(Pending event) those actions in service for further processing. Please provide code samples if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can start service on notification click by two ways :

**1) First Way :** You can call broadcast receiver when user clicks on notification.

> For this you need to use PendingIntent.getBroadcast instead of
>   getActivity().

Reference : [How to Start one Activity and two service on notification click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651982/how-to-start-one-activity-and-two-service-on-notification-click)

**2) Second Way :** You can directly start service when user clicks on notification.

> For this you need to use PendingIntent.getService instead of
>   getActivity().

Reference : [Start Service from Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422319/start-service-from-notification)

Comment: I don't want to start service on notification click. I need to listen the notification click in the already running service

Comment: @Dhakchianandan : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252065/refreshing-activity-on-receiving-gcm-push-notification